# Arduino program simply stops when looping through file listing

Tags: file, for-loop, mp3, arduino-uno

I'm having a hard hard time here. I have a sketch that's supposed to loop through a list of files on an SD card of the Adafruit Music Maker shield attached to my Arduino Uno V3 and play those mp3 files. My program used to work when I hardcoded directory names and did a simple loop like this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 127; i++)
```

but now, that I'm trying to make things more dynamic, it simply stops after showing the files, prior playing the first track.

Hardware wiring is ok, as I can hear the startup sound (hardcoded) being played.

Could someone knowledgeable take a look at below code and tell me why my program does not play the tracks. As aside note here, the console output is also a bit strange. It stops printing the directory listing at the last file but before completing the size of it.

This is my sketch:

```
// BOF preprocessor bug prevent - insert me on top of your arduino-code
#if 1
__asm volatile ("nop");
#endif
/*
   Fairytale Main program

   This programm will read an nfc tag. It will check for a directory name and optional a filename
   and start playing this on the music maker shield.

   Restrictions:
   1. All filenames must be in the format  trackXXX.mp3  - where XXX is a numbering from 001 to 127
   2. You can have a maximum of 127 files per directory - as I use a char to count the files to preserve memory
   3. All directory names must be exactly 8 chars long - use any combination of a-z and 0-9 chars for the name
   4. if a file is missing you will get a glitch in the sound while an error flashlight is lit up
*/

// make sure to change this to false before uploading in production as it turns on lots and lots of serial messages
boolean DEBUG = true;


// include the string header so we can use strcpy()
//#include <string.h>

//
// setup SPI, MP3 and SD libraries
//
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_VS1053.h>
#include <SD.h>
// These are the pins used for the music maker shield
#define SHIELD_RESET  -1     // VS1053 reset pin (unused!)
#define SHIELD_CS     7      // VS1053 chip select pin (output)
#define SHIELD_DCS    6      // VS1053 Data/command select pin (output)
#define CLK 13 // SPI Clock, shared with SD card
#define MISO 12 // Input data, from VS1053/SD card
#define MOSI 11 // Output data, to VS1053/SD card

// These are common pins between breakout and shield
#define CARDCS 4     // Card chip select pin
// DREQ should be an Int pin, see http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt
#define DREQ 3       // VS1053 Data request, ideally an Interrupt pin
// Create shield object
Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer musicPlayer = Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer(SHIELD_RESET, SHIELD_CS, SHIELD_DCS, DREQ, CARDCS);



// LIGHT EFFECTS
const byte ledPin = 9;                        // the pin to which the operation led is connected to
const byte warnPin = 9;                       // the pin to which the warning led is connected to
const byte errorPin = 9;                      // the pin to which the error led is connected to
boolean lightOff = false;                     // is set to true via a button, or after a certain amount of time - if true the operation fader light will be turned off

// uptime counters
unsigned long startUpTime = 0;
const uint8_t maxUpTime = 1800000;            // how long will the system stay on while nothing is playing - default 1800000 = 30 Minutes


// booleans to chose whether or not to show continuing warning messages in the loop
boolean loopWarningMessageNoFilesInDir = true;// make sure   no files in directory found   warning message is shown at least once
boolean loopWarningMessageFileNotFound = true;// make sure   file not found   warning message is shown at least once


// mp3 player variables
boolean plrStartPlaying = false;              // Is set to true in case an nfc tag is present with information on tracks to play
char plrCurrentFile[13] = "track001.mp3";     // which track is the player playing?
char plrCurrentFolder[9] = "system00";        // from which directory is the player playing?
char filename[23] = "/system00/track001.mp3"; // path and filename of the track to play
byte firstTrackToPlay = 1;                    // the track number as received from the tag
char curTrackCharNumber[4] = "001";

// volume control variables for the analog poti
const byte volumePotPin = A0;                 // the analog input pin that we use for the potentiometer
const byte sensorDrift = 7;                   // difference to last received sensor value that must be exceeded to activate a change in the volume
uint8_t compareValue = 0;                     // just a convenience variable to make comparison easier
uint8_t sensorValue = 0;                      // read the value from the potentiometer
uint8_t lastSensorValue = 0;                  // keeps the last read sensor value
byte soundVolume = 0;                         // the sound volume is derived via a map function from the sensor value


// other button settings
const byte btnLinePin = A1;                   // pin on which the button line (4 buttons) is connected
byte btnVal;                                  // stores the value we receive on the btnLinePin for comparance with the predefined analog reads for the 4 buttons
const byte btnValDrift = 20;                  // maximum allowed difference + and - the predefined value for each button we allow
const byte btnStop = 33;                      // The value we receive from analog input if the Stop (aka Home) Button is pressed
const byte btnPause = 66;                     // The value we receive from analog input if the Pause Button is pressed
const byte btnNext = 128;                     // The value we receive from analog input if the Next (aka Fast Forward) Button is pressed
const byte btnPrev = 230;                     // The value we receive from analog input if the Previos (aka Prev or Rewind) Button is pressed



// these are the prototypes for the nfc card reader
boolean getNfcCardData(void);                 // fill global vars with data from nfc tag and return true in case tag contains data or false if not
boolean writeNfcCardData(void);               // write the currently played track to the nfc tag, so we can start from there next time and return true for success and false in case of an error

// these are the prototypes for the mp3 player controller
byte getVolume(void);                         // function that returns the volume setting based on the analog read
void plrAdjustVolume(void);                   // function to check for changes on the volume control and adjust volume accrodingly
char plrStop(void);                           // stops the player and return 0
char plrPause(void);                          // pause and unpause the player and return 0
char playTrack(byte);                         // plays a track as defined by the global vars - and returns a -1 in case of an error, a 0 in case of success and a track number to play next in any other case

// these are the prototypes to work on files and general helpers
void printDirectory(File, byte);              // print out the content of specified directory on serial console
byte countFiles(File);                        // return the number of files in a directory passed as a File descriptor
boolean createFileNameToPlay(byte);           // creates the filename of the file to play from global vars plrCurrentFolder and plrCurrentFile and returns true if it exists

// these are the prototypes for the led info
void infoLed(void);                           // smooth dimming based on millis() during playback
void errorLed(void);                          // rapid flashing of error led
void warnLed(void);                           // up and down dimming of the warning led


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("Initializing all components")); }

  // initialize the music player
  if (! musicPlayer.begin()) {
    if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("VS1053 Not found")); }

    // flash the red light to indicate we have an error
    while (1) { errorLed(); }
  }
  //if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("Music Maker Shield VS1053 found")); }

  if (!SD.begin(CARDCS)) {
    if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("SD-Card Not found")); }

    // flash the red light to indicate we have an error
    while (1) { errorLed(); }
  }
  //if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("SD found and operational")); }

  // set the buttons as input
  pinMode(volumePotPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(btnLinePin, INPUT);

  // and the leds as output
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(warnPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(errorPin, OUTPUT);

  // This option uses a pin interrupt. No timers required! But DREQ
  // must be on an interrupt pin. For Uno/Duemilanove/Diecimilla
  // that's Digital #2 or #3
  // See http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt for other pins
  // *** This method is preferred
  if (! musicPlayer.useInterrupt(VS1053_FILEPLAYER_PIN_INT)) {
    if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("no interrupt on DREQ pin")); }
    while (1) { errorLed(); }
  }

  // here we play the welcome sound
  if (playTrack(1) == -1) {
    //if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("error playing startup sound!")); }
    warnLed();
  } else {
    // if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("startup sound played")); }
    // turn off all ligt effects
    analogWrite(ledPin, 0);
    analogWrite(warnPin, 0);
    analogWrite(errorPin, 0);
  }



  delay(1000); // wait some time for

  // check our current time, so we know when to stop
  startUpTime = millis();

  // if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("fairytale is up and running and ready to play audio")); printDirectory(SD.open("/"), 0); }
}



void loop() {



  if (true) {
    if (DEBUG) { Serial.println("NFC tag Found!\n"); }

    if (getNfcCardData()) {
      plrStartPlaying = true;
      // if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("Let us listen to some fine audio")); }
    } else {
      plrStartPlaying = false;
      if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("no directory entry on tag")); }
      warnLed();
    }
  }


  if (plrStartPlaying) {
    // now let's get the number of files in the album directory
    byte numberOfFiles = 0;
    numberOfFiles = countFiles(SD.open(plrCurrentFolder));


    // there is no file in the folder indicate this as a minor error
    if (numberOfFiles < 1) {
      if (!loopWarningMessageNoFilesInDir) {
        if (DEBUG) { Serial.print(F("No Files in directory ")); Serial.println(plrCurrentFolder); }
        loopWarningMessageNoFilesInDir = false; // set loop warning message so we don't show this warning in the next loop
      }

      // dim warning pin up and down to indicate we have a warning
      warnLed();
    } else {
      loopWarningMessageNoFilesInDir = true; // reset loop warning messages so we can reuse it for the next album
      loopWarningMessageFileNotFound = true;

      if (DEBUG) { Serial.print(F("Directory ")); Serial.print(plrCurrentFolder); Serial.print(F(" contains ")); Serial.print(numberOfFiles); Serial.println(F(" files")); printDirectory(SD.open(plrCurrentFolder), 1); }

      for (byte curTrack = firstTrackToPlay; curTrack <= numberOfFiles; curTrack++) {
        if (DEBUG) { Serial.print(F("working on file ")); Serial.print(curTrack); Serial.print(F(" / ")); Serial.println(numberOfFiles); }
        createFileNameToPlay(curTrack);
        if (1) {
          if (DEBUG) {Serial.print(F(" curTrack: "));Serial.print(curTrack);Serial.print(F(" / firstTrackToPlay: "));Serial.print(firstTrackToPlay);Serial.print(F(" / filename: "));Serial.println(filename); }

          // mp3 player functions playback
          // Start playing a file, then we can do stuff while waiting for it to finish

          // make sure we remember the just started track to be the new track, in case player is stopped
          if (curTrack != firstTrackToPlay) {
            if (DEBUG) { Serial.print(F("Writing ")); Serial.print(curTrack); Serial.print(F(" as first track on tag")); }
            firstTrackToPlay = curTrack;
            if (writeNfcCardData()) {
              if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F(" ... SUCCESS!")); }
            } else {
              if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F(" ... ERROR!")); }
              warnLed();
            }
          }

          // provide information on played track to serial console
          if (Serial.available()) {
            Serial.print(F("playing track ")); Serial.print(curTrack); Serial.print(F("/")); Serial.print(numberOfFiles); Serial.print(F(" ( ")); Serial.print(filename); Serial.println(F(")"));
            Serial.println(F("       To stop the playback enter   s   / to toggle pause enter   t"));
            Serial.println(F("       To play the next file enter  n   / for the previous enter  p"));
            Serial.println(F("       To toggle the light enter    l"));
          }

          char retVal = playTrack(curTrack);
          if (retVal == -1) {
            if (DEBUG) { Serial.print(F("ERROR playing file ")); Serial.println(filename); }
            warnLed();
          } else {
            // end of was playback successfull
            if (retVal == 0) {
              //if (DEBUG) { Serial.print(F("Done playing file ")); Serial.println(filename); }
              analogWrite(ledPin, 0);
            }
          }
          if (!musicPlayer.paused()) {
            analogWrite(ledPin, 0);
          }

        } else { // end of file found
          if (loopWarningMessageFileNotFound) {
            if (DEBUG) { Serial.print(filename); Serial.println(F(" does not exist.")); }
            loopWarningMessageFileNotFound = false; // set loop warning message so we don't show this warning in the next loop
            return (false);
          }
        } // end of file does not exist

      } // end of loop through files

    } // end of check if at least 1 file was found

    // now, as everything is played, set plrStartPlaying to false again to prevent endless looping through the album
    plrStartPlaying = false;
  } // end of check on boolean var plrStartPlaying

} // end of loop



//  At the moment we fake NFC operations
//
boolean getNfcCardData() {
  boolean usableContent = true;  // in case the tag has everything we need to play an album - in essence there must be a message with the directory - we return this as true
  strcpy(plrCurrentFolder, "bluemc99");   // comment this out, once the NFC tag reader works
  firstTrackToPlay = 2;                   // this too has to be commented out in case the nfc tag reader works

// write the tag data
boolean writeNfcCardData(void) {
  boolean error = false;  // in case we have an error
  return (error);
}



//  BELOW THIS LINE THE MP3 PLAYER CONTROL IS DEFINED
//
byte getVolume() {
  //soundVolume = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 100); // map the sensor value to a sound volume
  soundVolume = sensorValue / 10; // map the sensor value to a sound volume
  // if (DEBUG) { Serial.print(F("last sensor value: ")); Serial.print(lastSensorValue); Serial.print(F(" / new sensor value: ")); Serial.print(sensorValue); Serial.print(F(" / volume: ")); Serial.println(soundVolume); }
  lastSensorValue = sensorValue;
  return (soundVolume);
}


// included in while loop during playback to check for volume changes
void plrAdjustVolume() {
  // volume control functions
  // read the input on analog pin 0 and check if we have a change in volume.
  sensorValue = analogRead(volumePotPin);
  if (lastSensorValue > sensorValue) {
    compareValue = lastSensorValue - sensorValue;
  } else {
    compareValue = sensorValue - lastSensorValue;
  }
  // If we have a high enough difference in the sensor reading, calculate it so we may set it on the player

  if (compareValue > sensorDrift) {
    // if (DEBUG) { Serial.print(F("changing volume: ")); }
    soundVolume = getVolume();
    musicPlayer.setVolume(soundVolume, soundVolume);
  } // end of change sound volume
}

// stop playback
char plrStop(void) {
  // if (DEBUG) { Serial.println(F("Stopping playback")); }
  musicPlayer.stopPlaying();
  return(0);
}

// toggle pause
int8_t plrTogglePause(void) {
  if (!musicPlayer.paused()) {
    musicPlayer.pausePlaying(true);
  } else {
    musicPlayer.pausePlaying(false);
  }
  return (0);
}

char playTrack(byte trackNo) {
  if (!musicPlayer.startPlayingFile(filename)) {
    if (DEBUG) { Serial.println("Music Player did not start playback"); }
    return (-1);
  }

  //
  //    LETS PLAY THE TRACK
  //
  while (musicPlayer.playingMusic) { //|| musicPlayer.paused) {
    // file is now playing in the 'background' so now's a good time
    // to do something else like handling LEDs or buttons :)

    // fade the light
    infoLed();

    // check for changes to volme and adjust accordingly
    plrAdjustVolume();

    // check for serial input / or button presses to pause, play next or previous track
    // a simple console interface to work with the player

    if (Serial.available()) {
      char c = Serial.read();
      // if we get an 's' on the serial console, stop!
      if (c == 's') {
        Serial.print(c);Serial.println(F(" - stop"));
        delay(10);
        return (plrStop());
      }

      // if we get an  'p'  on the serial console, pause/unpause!
      if (c == 't') {
        Serial.print(c); Serial.println(F(" - pause/resume"));
        delay(10);
        plrTogglePause();
      }

      // if we get an  'f'  on the serial console, play next track
      if (c == 'n') {
        Serial.print(c); Serial.println(F(" - next"));
        delay(10);
        trackNo = trackNo + 1;
        return (trackNo);
      }

      // if we get an  'r'  on the serial console, play previous track
      if (c == 'p') {
        Serial.print(c); Serial.println(F(" - prev"));
        delay(10);
        trackNo = trackNo - 1;
        return (trackNo);
      }

      // if we get an  'l'  on the serial console, turn off th light effect
      if (c == 'l') {
        if (lightOff) lightOff = false;
        else lightOff = true;
      }
    } // end of console interface
    /*
        btnVal = analogRead(btnLinePin);
        if (btnVal > (btnStop - btnValDrift) && btnVal < (btnStop + btnValDrift)) return(plrStop());
        if (btnVal > (btnPause - btnValDrift) && btnVal < (btnPause + btnValDrift)) plrTogglePause();
        if (btnVal > (btnNext - btnValDrift) && btnVal < (btnNext + btnValDrift)) trackNo = trackNo + 1; return(trackNo);;
        if (btnVal > (btnPrev - btnValDrift) && btnVal < (btnPrev + btnValDrift)) trackNo = trackNo - 1; return(trackNo);
    */
    // check if the maximum alotted time for the light fader was reached and if so make sure fader is turned off
    if (millis() - startUpTime > maxUpTime) lightOff = true;

    if (!musicPlayer.playingMusic) return (0);
  } // end of while playing music

  return (trackNo);
}


// BELOW THIS LINE THE FILE HELPER FUNCTIONS CAN BE FOUND
//
// counts the number of files in directory
byte countFiles(File dir) {
  byte counter = 0;
  while (true) {
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    // Skip directories and hidden files.
    //if (!entry.isSubDir() && !entry.isHidden()) {
    if (!entry) {
      // no more files
      break;
    }
    counter++;
    entry.close();
    //}
  }
  dir.close();
  //delay(counter*10); // wait number of elements in dir * 10 milliseconds for the console to settle
  return (counter);
}

// stores the file to play in the global var filename - it is created from the gloal vars plrCurrentFolder and plrCurrentFile
boolean createFileNameToPlay(byte trackNo) {
  // fill global var curTrackCharNumber with provided trackNo - we need it next to create the global var plrCurrentFile
  sprintf(curTrackCharNumber, "%03d", trackNo);

  // create the name of the track to play from the curTrack
  strcpy(plrCurrentFile[0], '\0');
  strcat(plrCurrentFile, "track");
  strcat(plrCurrentFile, curTrackCharNumber);
  //strcat(plrCurrentFile, sprintf(plrCurrentFile, "%03d", trackNo));
  strcat(plrCurrentFile, ".mp3");

  // create the filename of the track to play, including path, so we can feed it to the music player
  strcpy(filename[0], '\0');
  strcat(filename, "/");
  strcat(filename, plrCurrentFolder);
  strcat(filename, "/");
  strcat(filename, plrCurrentFile);

  if (SD.exists(filename)) {
    return (true);
  } else {
    return (false);
  }
}


// File listing helper
void printDirectory(File dir, byte numTabs) {
  while (true) {
    File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
    // no more files
    if (! entry) {
      break;
    }

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
      Serial.print('\t');
    }

    Serial.print(entry.name());
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      Serial.println(F("/"));
      printDirectory(entry, numTabs + 1);
    } else {
      // files have sizes, directories do not
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(entry.size(), DEC);
    }
    entry.close();
  } // end while
}

void infoLed(void) {
  if (!lightOff) analogWrite(ledPin, 128 + 127 * cos(2 * PI / 20000 * millis()));
}
void errorLed(void) {
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    analogWrite(errorPin, 0); delay(5); analogWrite(errorPin, 255); delay(5);
  }
}
void warnLed(void) {
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 255; i++) analogWrite(warnPin, i); delay(10);
  for (uint8_t i = 255; i = 0; i--) analogWrite(warnPin, i); delay(10);
}
```